# Get index from array comparing a property of each index in the array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

**Can I do this?**

```
Array.IndexOf(Array, (index.propery == true))
```

Where index equals IndexOf's own incrementer.

**Why I'm asking**:
I'm using Unity, I have a number of objects which are components of a larger, or whole, object in the game. I want to use Unity's editor to assign these Objects to their variables in the game. I later need to iterate over these objects. I would like to do this by having them in an array (as unity can still edit these). The problem begins where in an array I cant access the objects with a meaning-full index. I would like to refer to the components by name, a dictionary is not accessible to by Unity (and incurres a performance overhead).

My solution, which I'm asking whether is possible is to access the array index by searching for it with IndexOf(), but can I do it by searching with the name of the GameObject at each index?

```
GameObject result = Array.IndexOf(GOArray, GOArray[INDEX].gameObject.name == "theoneiwant")
```

Comment: you can use lambda Expressions for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Array.Find:

```
GameObject result = Array.Find(GOArray, g => g.name == "theoneiwant");
```

Just pay attention it is not very efficient. If you want speed, you best use dictionary, maybe pre-build your dictionary from an array on startup.

Answer (score 0):

try this for getting index

```
var index = Array.FindIndex(yourArray, gameobj => gameobj.propery == true);
```

**UPDATE**
OK maybe i didn't understand your question very well.

- If your `GameObjects` have **unique** names you can simply find them by their  name, it's fast and reliable:

  ```
  public GameObject targetObj;
  targetObj = GameObject.Find("objectname");
  ```
- but if they haven't you can create a List of GameObjects, assign your gameObjects to it and then search through them with this code:

  ```
  public List<GameObject> myObjList = new List<GameObject>();  
  public GameObject targetObj;
  targetObj= myObjList.Where(x => x.name == "objectname").SingleOrDefault();
  ```

use name or any attribute you want to find them.